# How to Compare and Highlight Duplicate Rows in Ag-Grid with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, duplicates, ag-grid

I'm trying to get ag-grid to highlight duplicate rows by comparing the id, name, and description.

```
values = [ 
     { id: 10, name: 'axel', desc: 'it's me' }, 
     { id: 10, name: 'axel', desc: 'not me' }, 
     { id: 11, name: 'payton',  desc: 'hello I'm payton'}, 
     { id: 10, name: 'axel', desc: 'it's me' }                         
    ];
```

the row that will be highlighted should be ...

```
values = [ 
        { id: 10, name: 'axel', desc: 'it's me' }, 
        { id: 10, name: 'axel', desc: 'it's me' } 
         ];
```

There may be new objects inserted into the array without an id but I would still like to remove the objects with the same name and description.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ag-grid but if you want to find the duplicated object you can do this

```js
const values = [ 
     { id: 10, name: 'axel', desc: "it's me" }, 
     { id: 10, name: 'axel', desc: 'not me' }, 
     { id: 11, name: 'payton',  desc: "hello I'm payton"}, 
     { id: 10, name: 'axel', desc: "it's me" }                         
    ];
    
    
const findDuplicated = data =>  Object.values(data.reduce((res, item) => {
  const key = JSON.stringify(item)
  return {
    ...res,
    [key]: [...(res[key] || []), item]
  }
}, {})).filter(item => item.length > 1).flat()

console.log(findDuplicated(values))


console.log(findDuplicated(values.map(({name, desc}) => ({name, desc}))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should've added this to the question but I'm trying to figure out how to compare by specific properties in the object. Some objects may be inserted into the array with out an id and I would still like to remove those with the same name and description

Comment: @Austin I modified my response so you can call it as a function to whatever array you want. Just transform the data and pass the resulting array as argument